# How can I store credit card information securely on my computer?

Tags: macos, security, operating-systems

I want to store my credit card details on my Mac, but I know the security risks involved with just leaving it in a text file.

Is there an app for OS X that is able to encrypt data like this? I am aware of TrueCrypt, but that feels like more of a cludge.

Answer (score 5):

The built-in app, [Keychain Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_Access), can do this in the *Secure Notes* category. The linked article was written for Mac OS 10.4, but still applies.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh1616.html

You can also create a small, read/write, encrypted DMG with [Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility) and store your text file in there.

Additionally, [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password) is amazing, but also $40.

Answer (score 4):

You can user [**KeePassX**](http://www.keepassx.org/).

[image]

> KeePassX saves many different
>   information e.g. user names,
>   passwords, urls, attachments and
>   comments in one single database. For a
>   better management user-defined titles
>   and icons can be specified for each
>   single entry. Furthermore the entries
>   are sorted in groups, which are
>   customizable as well. The integrated
>   search function allows to search in a
>   single group or the complete database.
>
> The complete database is always
>   encrypted either with AES (alias
>   Rijndael) or Twofish encryption
>   algorithm using a 256 bit key.
>   Therefore the saved information can be
>   considered as quite safe. KeePassX
>   uses a database format that is
>   compatible with KeePass Password Safe.
>   This makes the use of that application
>   even more favourable.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X's built-in Keychain Access utility has the ability to store "secure notes".

/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app

File > New Secure Note Item…

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned keychain is a good tool to store passwords. When it comes to things like creditcards etc my absolute favorite app is [1 Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password).

If you *only* want to store a creditcard it might be a bit overkill to get 1 password, but it has a lot of nice features.

- auto generate passwords and auto film it in on registration forms.
- works with safari and Firefox and can auto fill username and passwords for your sites.
- you can store items like db access, server access etc setup with all the unique info you need for each type.
- iPhone app that can sync via wifi or dropbox.

This is just a summary over the most important stuff. It's also a very polished app that's nice and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

While both build-in Keychain or 1Password do the job I suggest using **Keypass** or **TrueCrypt**. They are both cross-platform, as long as the datafile can be rescued you can access your crucial data from any system.